# Jquery check the checkbox in td before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a table in html with td contains a checkbox input like this

```
<table id="my_table">
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="td1"></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="td2"></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="td3"></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="td4"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
<script>
$('[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
       $(this).closest('td').prev().find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
</script>
```

I wanna create a function in jquery that when I check a checkbox the one above it is checked (example if td3 is checked then td1 is checked also) but the one i used check the input next to this and not above it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `index()` to get index of clicked checkbox td and accordingly check another previous checkbox

```js
$('[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
    index = $(this).closest('td').index();
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
       $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('input:checkbox').eq(index).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my_table">
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="td1"></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="td2"></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="td3"></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="td4"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: I think he wants a generic code like if he clicks the third checkbox, third checkbox of the first tr element should have checked.

Comment: Thank you but with :first and when i check for example "td4" I got "td1" is checked but i want the one above ("td2" in my example)

Comment: Good except any previously defined `index` variable (outside the scope of this function) is going to get clobbered.

Answer (score 1):

One approach, though using plain JavaScript rather than jQuery, is to assign an event-listener, for the `change` event, to the parent `<td>` element. From there find its `cellIndex` property to find the correct cell, and descendant `<input>`, in the previous row, to change:

```
// retrieve the <table> element, by its id property:
var table = document.getElementById('my_table'),

  // find all the <td> elements within the <table>:
  cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td'),

  // convert the collection of <td> elements
  // into an Array (using an ES5 approach because
  // of my work browser):
  cellArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(cells, 0);

  // if ES6 is available to you the following would
  // be more concise:
  // cellArray = Array.from( cells );

// iterating over the Array of cells:
cellArray.forEach(function(cell) {
  // 'cell', the first argument, is a reference to
  //         the current array-element (a <td> node)
  //         of the Array over which we're iterating.

  // here we add the event-listener for the 'change'
  // event, using the anonymous method to handle the
  // functionality:
  cell.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

    // 'this' is the <td> element, the 'cell' variable:
    var index = this.cellIndex,

      // e is the event-object passed into the
      // anonymous function,
      // e.target is the element that triggered
      // the event we were listening for, the
      // descendant <input>; the checked property
      // is Boolean, and will return true if it's
      // checked and false if not:
      checked = e.target.checked,

      // the parentNode of a <td> is the <tr>:
      row = this.parentNode,

      // the previous <tr> element is the
      // previousElementSibling (the first
      // of the element's previous-siblings
      // that is also an element, so excluding
      // textNodes, commentNodes etc:
      previousRow = row.previousElementSibling;

    // if we have a previous row:
    if (previousRow) {
      // we find its children (which are elements,
      // children is different from childNodes):
      previousRow.children[index]
        // we then find the first, if any, <input>
        // element with a 'type' property of 'checkbox':
        .querySelector('input[type=checkbox]')
        // and set its checked state to the same
        // Boolean value as the <input> which fired the
        // the change event:
        .checked = checked;
    }

  });
});
```

```js
var table = document.getElementById('my_table'),
  cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td'),
  cellArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(cells, 0);

cellArray.forEach(function(cell) {
  cell.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var index = this.cellIndex,
      checked = e.target.checked,
      row = this.parentNode,
      previousRow = row.previousElementSibling;

    if (previousRow) {
      previousRow.children[index].querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').checked = checked;
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<table id="my_table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="td1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="td2">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="td3">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="td4">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="td5">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="td6">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="td7">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="td8">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zu4Lb1pz/).

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`HTMLTableCellElement` properties, including `cellIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`Node.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes).
- [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).
- [`NonDocumentTypeChildNode.previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling).
- [`ParentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children).

Comment: Well, nobody can say you aren't thorough. Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example. It uses `index()` to get the clicked cell's index. Then selects the previous row and finds the respective checkbox:

```js
$('[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
    var that = $(this);
    // Get clicked cell's index
    var index = that.closest('td').index();
    // Get previous row's cell with same index
    var aboveTd = that.closest('tr').prev('tr').find('td').eq(index).find('input[type=checkbox]');
    // Toggle checked state
    aboveTd.prop('checked', that.is(":checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my_table">
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="td1"></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="td2"></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="td3"></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="td4"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
$('[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).closest('tr').prev().has('input[type="checkbox"]')) {
    var idx = $(this).closest('td').index();
    $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td:eq(' + idx + ') input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my_table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="td1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="td2">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="td3">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="td4">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```